# What is the purpose of Django's phone2numeric method in the utils library?

Tags: python, django, function

Django has the following function `phone2numeric(phone)` defined below:

```
def phone2numeric(phone):
    """Convert a phone number with letters into its numeric equivalent."""
    char2number = {
        'a': '2', 'b': '2', 'c': '2', 'd': '3', 'e': '3', 'f': '3', 'g': '4',
        'h': '4', 'i': '4', 'j': '5', 'k': '5', 'l': '5', 'm': '6', 'n': '6',
        'o': '6', 'p': '7', 'q': '7', 'r': '7', 's': '7', 't': '8', 'u': '8',
        'v': '8', 'w': '9', 'x': '9', 'y': '9', 'z': '9',
    }
    return ''.join(char2number.get(c, c) for c in phone.lower())
```

From the looks of it it basically takes a number e.g. 1-800 GALAXY and turns the GALAXY part to 425299 so it becomes 1-800 425299. I'm just wondering why Django has implemented such a specific function?

Comment: Remember Django was first written for the Lawrence Journal-World newspaper in Kansas. Presumably they had a use for this filter.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to convert text of phone number from a mobile layout to a real phone number. A sample layout and a demonstration are attached below.

```
[![In \[14\]: def phone2numeric(phone):
    ...:         """Converts a phone number with letters into its numeric equivalent."""
    ...:         char2number = {
    ...:             'a': '2', 'b': '2', 'c': '2', 'd': '3', 'e': '3', 'f': '3', 'g': '4',
    ...:             'h': '4', 'i': '4', 'j': '5', 'k': '5', 'l': '5', 'm': '6', 'n': '6',
    ...:             'o': '6', 'p': '7', 'q': '7', 'r': '7', 's': '7', 't': '8', 'u': '8',
    ...:             'v': '8', 'w': '9', 'x': '9', 'y': '9', 'z': '9',
    ...:         }
    ...:         return ''.join(char2number.get(c, c) for c in phone.lower())
    ...: 

In \[15\]: phone = "ghab3wmded"

In \[16\]: phone2numeric(phone)
Out\[16\]: '4422396333'

In \[17\]:][1]][1]
```